# creating subdomains with apache on debian; creating hgweb subdomain as second step

Tags: apache, mercurial, subdomain, hgweb

After hours of trying to setup subdomains on my dedicated root server, I'm asking you for help.

Target:

- being able to create and access subdomains
- setup an own subdomain for mercurial repositories, using hgweb

Information about the server:

- Debian Linux, Kernel 2.6.32-028stab094.3
- Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
- Mercurial 1.6.4
- libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 installed

**First question: what is wrong with my apache configuration that I can't access my subdomains via the browser?**

Actually, I can access the root domain and the sites which are installed there.

My configuration:
**/etc/apache2/sites-available/default**

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName mydomain.tld
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.tld

    DocumentRoot /var/www/forum
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/forum>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/hgrepos.domainname.tld**

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName hgrepos.domainname.tld
    ServerAlias www.hgrepos.domainname.tld
    DocumentRoot /var/www/hgrepos/htdocs

    # WSGIScriptAliasMatch ^(.*)$ /var/www/hgrepos/cgi-bin/hgweb.wsgi$1
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/hgrepos/cgi-bin/hgweb.wsgi

    # To enable "daemon" mode, uncomment following lines. (Read mod_wsgi docs for more info)
    # WSGIDaemonProcess hgrepos.domainname.tld user=USER group=GROUP threads=1 processes=15 maximum-requests=1000
    WSGIDaemonProcess hgrepos.domainname.tld  threads=1 processes=15 maximum-requests=1000
    # some more interesting options (tested on mod_wsgi 2.0):
    # umask=0007 display-name=wsgi-hg.example.net inactivity-timeout=300
    # WSGIProcessGroup hg.example.net

    <Directory /var/www/hgrepos/htdocs>
        Options FollowSymlinks
        DirectoryIndex index.html

        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/hgrepos/cgi-bin>
        Options ExecCGI FollowSymlinks

        AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi

        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My **/etc/apache2/httpd.conf** file is empty.

I enabled the subdomain file via `a2ensite subdomain.domainname.tld`.

```
regine@diddi:/etc/apache2/sites-available# ll ../sites-enabled/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Oct 29 22:33 000-default -> ../sites-available/default
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 48 Nov 17 00:41 hgrepos.domainname.tld -> ../sites-available/hgrepos.domainname.tld
```

I used both, `/etc/init.d/apache2 reload` and `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`. Apache didn't tell me that I tried to load a malformed configuration.

The sites for the root domain are under `/var/www/forum` and accessible.

My folder structure for **/var/www/hgrepos** looks like:

```
hgrepos
+- drwxr-xr-x www-data www-data cgi-bin
|--- -rwxr-xr-x www-data www-data hgweb.config
|--- -rwxr-xr-x www-data www-data hgweb.wsgi
+-- drwxr-xr-x htdocs
|--- -rw-r--r-- www-data www-data index.html
|--- drwxr-xr-x www-data www-data myFirstHgRep
```

The `index.html` file just contains some Hello World! html to see if the subdomain is accessible.

So now back to my first question: why can't I access to the **hgrepos** subdomain via my browser?

Now second, I want to serve some mercurial (hg) repositories for my private projects, using `hgweb`. I followed those instructions:
https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/modwsgi
https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStepFtpOnly

Here are my config files under **/var/www/hgrepos/cgi-bin/**:

**hgweb.wsgi**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# An example hgweb CGI script, edit as necessary
# See also https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories

# Path to repo or hgweb config to serve (see 'hg help hgweb')
# config = "hgweb.config"

# Uncomment and adjust if Mercurial is not installed system-wide:
#import sys; sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/python/lib")

# Uncomment to send python tracebacks to the browser if an error occurs:
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

from mercurial import demandimport; demandimport.enable()
from mercurial.hgweb import hgweb, wsgicgi
application = hgweb("hgweb.config")
#wsgicgi.launch(application)
```

**hgweb.config**

```
[web]
style = coal
baseurl =

[paths]
/ = /var/www/hgrepos/htdocs/*
```

Rights of the files:

```
regine@diddi:/var/www/hgrepos/cgi-bin# ll 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data  68 Nov 17 01:16 hgweb.config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 621 Nov 17 01:24 hgweb.wsgi
```

**So now my second question: how can I get hgweb working? What's actually wrong with my configuration?**

Well, wow, this is much of text, but I'm not quite sure which information are needed and which aren't. Hope you can help me, any hint is helpful :)

Comment: I haven't time to look at the config in its entirety, but a quick question, what about the DNS resolving of the subdomain ? Are your DNS server configured to respond to request about your subdomain ?

Comment: Aw, you're right, thank you for the hint. At least this was missing, I will inform you if this solved the problem, too

Comment: Thank you krtek, this solved at least my first problem - that I can't access my subdomains! Great, thank you! Now I need to fix the hgweb-stuff...

Comment: Glad I could help... If I have some times today I will try to look at your configuration problem.

Comment: Hey krtek, would be pretty nice. I'm working on it now, but I still get a 500 Internal Server error. I'll have a look at the logs and retry a little bit, I'll update you as soon as I have some news.

Comment: Hmm, having some numerous looks at the error log, I see this:
mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.1.2.
mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.1.3.
mod_wsgi (pid=16013): Target WSGI script '/var/www/hgrepos/cgi-bin/hgweb.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=16013): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/hgrepos/cgi-bin/hgweb.wsgi'.
...
ImportError: No module named hgweb_mod


I'll need to check if there is a version incompatibility for the mod_wsgi compiled version against its runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, good news - I fixed my issues.

First step was removing libapache-mod-wsgi-py3 and installing libapache-mod-wsgi (during my tries I re-installed wsgi-py3-package several times, seems like my last re-installation fixed that somehow...)

```
apt-get remove libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
apt-get install libapach2-mod-wsgi-py3
apt-get autoremove
```

After that, restarting apache got me the following in my error.log:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=16349): Target WSGI script '/var/www/hgrepos/cgi-bin/hgweb.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=16349): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/hgrepos/cgi-bin/hgweb.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/hgrepos/cgi-bin/hgweb.wsgi", line 20, in <module>
    application = hgweb("/var/www/hgrepos/cgi-bin/hgweb.config")
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mercurial/hgweb/hgweb_mod.py", line 32, in __init__
    self.repo = hg.repository(u, repo)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mercurial/hg.py", line 94, in repository
    repo = _lookup(path).instance(ui, path, create)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mercurial/bundlerepo.py", line 305, in instance
    return bundlerepository(ui, repopath, bundlename)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mercurial/bundlerepo.py", line 177, in __init__
    raise util.Abort(_("%s: not a Mercurial bundle file") % bundlename)
Abort: /var/www/hgrepos/cgi-bin/hgweb.config: not a Mercurial bundle file
```

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868365/hosting-mercurial-on-iis7), I set up my hgweb.wsgi-file like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#

# Uncomment and adjust if Mercurial is not installed system-wide:
#import sys; sys.path.insert(0, "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6")

# Uncomment to send python tracebacks to the browser if an error occurs:
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

from mercurial import demandimport; demandimport.enable()
from mercurial.hgweb import hgweb, wsgicgi

# Path to repo or hgweb config to serve (see 'hg help hgweb')
config = "/var/www/hgrepos/cgi-bin/hgweb.config"
application = hgweb(config)
```

Restarting Apache

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

and now everything works for me.

A big THANKS again to krtek who really helped out ending my pain! Made my day :D