# How to set up an ******.domain.com

Tags: url, testing

pretty simple question but one that I really have no idea how to search for.

I have a domain, let's call it example.com, and I want to set up a testing site with the same domain but at a different URL, let's say beta.example.com.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using cpanel or something like that provided from your hosting company - Go to your Cpanel > domains > sub-domains > **Create a Subdomain**. There you will find information for creating a subdomain.

Answer (score 3):

A sub-domain is just a DNS record pointing to a subdirectory of your website.  First you create the site in a subdirectory for the site under public_html (or inetpub\wwwroot\  for IIS), and then match it with a DNS record.  Most of the work is done by wizards, but here are the basics.

If you are self-hosting, it depends on your server.

Here is a similar post on StackOverflow with IIS 7:
[How to set up subdomains on IIS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069278/how-to-set-up-subdomains-on-iis-7)

Here is one on Apache:
[Stackoverflow, Apache Sub-domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190499/creating-subdomains-with-apache-on-debian-creating-hgweb-subdomain-as-second-st)

If you are using a hosting company (like GoDaddy, RoutHost, etc), there will be a FAQ or help file on the host, search for Creating (or managing) a sub-domain ([GoDaddy Manage SubDomains](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4652/managing-your-hosting-account-subdomains))

Comment: Thanks! I just couldn't figure out/remember the word "subdomain"